# Index for SQL join

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am doing a join on 3 tables and for some reason I can't get an index to be used on one of the tables.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM nfl_schedules ns
join nfl_daily_fantasy_players dfs
    on dfs.date = ns.date and dfs.team = ns.home_team
left join fantasy_salaries sal
    on sal.platform_id = (SELECT id FROM platforms p WHERE p.platform = 'draft_kings') and sal.game_key = ns.game_key and  sal.player_id = dfs.player_id
left join nfl_players np
    on np.player_id = dfs.player_id
where ns.timeframe = @frame;
```

I have an index on dfs for the fields `(date, team)` and `(date, team, player_id)` and neither are being applied.  It is the only table that does not have an index being applied. In the extra it says it is using where.

Any ideas?

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,PRIMARY,dfs,ALL,"date_team,date_team_player_id",NULL,NULL,NULL,4920,"Using where"
1,PRIMARY,ns,ref,"date_team_timeframe,date_team",date_team_timeframe,264,"draftcrunch_new.dfs.date,draftcrunch_new.dfs.team",1,"Using index condition"
1,PRIMARY,sal,ref,"unique,index3,index4,index5",index4,262,"draftcrunch_new.dfs.player_id,draftcrunch_new.ns.game_key",1,"Using where"
1,PRIMARY,np,ref,"unique_players,index3",unique_players,4,draftcrunch_new.dfs.player_id,1,NULL
2,SUBQUERY,p,const,platform,platform,257,const,1,"Using index"
```

Comment: Post explain plan

Comment: Not sure the best way to format it. But there it is.  On line one it isn't using an index for dfs.

Comment: Can you show your create index statements on dfs?

Comment: I used mysqlworkbench GUI but here are the indexes: (date, team, player_id), (player_id), (date, team)

Comment: I suggest trying to isolate this further. Narrow your query down to 2 table join. If the symptom still persists, post both tables' `show create table` output and corresponding explain plan. On the other hand, if the symptom only shows when you join all these tables, then that's a good piece of information to have too.

Answer (score 0):

```
where  ns.timeframe = @frame        --> INDEX(timeframe)
ON dfs.date = ns.date and  dfs.team = ns.home_team
                                    --> INDEX(team, date)
WHERE  p.platform = 'draft_kings'   --> INDEX(platform)
sal.platform_id = ( SELECT...)      --> Use JOIN, not IN
sal.platform_id = ...
      and  sal.game_key = ns.game_key
      and  sal.player_id = dfs.player_id
                 --> INDEX(game_key, player_id, platform_id) (in any order)
ON np.player_id = dfs.player_id     --> INDEX(player_id)
```

Keep in mind:

- `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key is an `INDEX`;
- When you have `INDEX(a), INDEX(a,b)`, the first is redundant.

[*Index cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

If you need more help, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.